# Android : Removing border in rating bar

Tags: java, android, xml, ratingbar

I am using default `rating bar` in android and there is a weird grey border is been showing, I want to remove them.

Please Note :: Many answers on stackoverflow suggest to use own images but I don't want to, Is there is any method to remove border?

My code ::

```
  <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_home_recycler_view_rating_bar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="4.0"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" />
```

What I am getting

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the image here

Comment: update your answer so we can help you

Comment: @Ravi Which grey border are you talking about?The border around selcted stars ?

Comment: @Soham Yes border around selected stars

Comment: @Ravi I don't  think it's possible. You have to use your custom style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

From your layout

Answer (score 0):

Create custom style to your rating bar

```
<style name="RatingBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">34dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">34dp</item>
</style>
```

your rating bar selector

drawable/ratingbar_selector.xml

```
<item android:id="@+android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/..." />

<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/..." />

<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/..." />
```

Comment: I don't want to use drawable, I have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Any other solution please?

Comment: provide your xml code then and how your image look like , may be you miss some attributs

Comment: Edited Code Please Check

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
RatingBar coachRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rcoach_rbr_rating);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) coachRating.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), 
                        R.color.colorAccent),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for filled stars
stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), 
                        R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for half filled stars
stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(), 
                        R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for empty stars
```

Reference: [How can I set the color of android rating bar's stroke? (Not the color of the stars but the BORDER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378098/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-android-rating-bars-stroke-not-the-color-of-the-st)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it don't need images.

```
public static void setRatingStyle(RatingBar ratingbar, int ratingNormalColor, int ratingProgressColor) {
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingbar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(ratingNormalColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(ratingProgressColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Comment: it only chnages color, doesn't remove border

Comment: I don't think it's possible with out drawables