# How can I set the color of android rating bar's stroke? (Not the color of the stars but the BORDER)

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, ratingbar

I am an android beginner and I want to make my custom ratingBar.

Disclaimer: it's not a duplicate. because all the posts I have read asks about how to change colors of the star and how to remove the stroke. That is NOT what I want. I want to have the stroke and to be able to change the color of the border.

With a transparent and yellow stroke while empty, and yellow background and stroke for half and filled.

I do NOT want to use pngs. I have my own already but they are too small. I just dont want to ask the designer to make new ones if I can make the stars using only XML attributes and drawables.

```
<RatingBar
          android:id="@+id/thread_rating"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:isIndicator="true"
          android:numStars="5"
          android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/gray"
          android:progressTint="@color/gold"
          android:rating="2.5"
          android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/gray"
          android:stepSize="0.5"
          style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
          />
```

I work on this with another engineer. He also wrote code in a java file

```
private void setRatingBarStart(RatingBar rating_bar) {
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) rating_bar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2)
    .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for filled stars
stars.getDrawable(1)
    .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for half filled stars
stars.getDrawable(0)
    .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for empty stars
```

[So now it has a grey background, yellow for filled, and NO stroke now.

[image]

And I want it to have transparent background, yellow stroke and yellow for filled.
Looks like this 
[image]

I already know how to set the background transparent and to make it yellow. I just dont know how to set the stroke color. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android RatingBar change star colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors)

Comment: Look at this thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android
Just set three different png for stras(empty, filled and half filled) with stroke and inner colour and the job is done

Comment: @AlessioTrecani  Hi Thanks for your comment. I do NOT want pngs. I have them already but they are too small. I try not to ask the designer to make new ones if I can set the stars up with the XML attributes

Comment: @huskylove check my answer.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the PNGs, you can set the size you want, and I think that's the only solution if you want a custom rating bar.

Answer (score 18):

Put all drawable color to Yellow(*in your case `getResources().getColor(R.color.gold)` for all*) for set strokes and background. *(for background,secondary progress and progress)*

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

remove `progressBackgroundTint`,`progressTint`,`secondaryProgressTint` attributes from `RatingBar` no need of it.

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="2.5"/>
```

*and result is ::*

[image: image1]

Hope this will help *(pink color is just background color)*

*after set drawable 1 and 0 to red:*

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

[image: image2]

Comment: The question is: how do I change the stroke color only? For example, take the stars in your example and add a red border to them.

Comment: KDeogharkar, your answer is simple, clear and correctly addresses the issue. I will probably award you the bounty. However that'd be really great if you could help me with my previous question -- because that's the goal I'm trying to achieve and the reason why I've started this bounty.

Comment: means you want to change colors of border for example yellow strokes to red?  is this what you want? @vitorsdcs

Comment: if I understand your question well you can change `drawable(0)` and `drawable(1)`color to red like `stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` it will change your border and partially fill border. 3rd layerdrawable will be yellow only for fill part

Comment: No, I wanted it to look kind of like the first star in this image: http://i.imgur.com/dhGaCdX.png (yellow fill, dark-blue stroke). If I change drawable(0) and drawable(1) the way you said, it actually looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/hQH3vCO.png

Comment: I dont get it . @vitorsdcs why your result and mine is different? please see my updated answer . I have also set 0 and 1 drawable to red .

Comment: Am I the only one who receives colour fill instead of the stroke?

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder No i also got the color fills instead of stroke, might be it varies on different OS. I am testing on LG nexus 5 (OS:6.0.1, API:23), Please update about your recent experience.

Comment: This does not give stroked, though that may be dependent on default star of OS. See Yoann Hercouet's answer below, with link to where we can download proper stroked star

Answer (score 9):

Don't use any library or style for that. Use bellow step you get the result.

create a file in drawable folder as custom_ratingbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

then use following in your RatingBar :

```
  <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarChef"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.2"
    android:rating="3.0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    />
```

Comment: is working fine - but i can just see single star my friend

Comment: i got whats my problem - i use Vector , i should replace it with an PNG star

Answer (score 5):

I think I actually found what you need. You will have to create a custom `RatingBar`as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800686/2206688) BUT you will have to use vector drawables and not standard ones.

You can download the 3 drawables (full, half and empty) on this website:

https://materialdesignicons.com/

Or by doing a right click on your `res` folder: --> New --> Vector asset on Android Studio.

Here are the 3 drawables XML in case you don't find them:

Full star:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z" />
```

Half star:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M12,15.89V6.59L13.71,10.63L18.09,11L14.77,13.88L15.76,18.16M22,9.74L14.81,9.13L12,2.5L9.19,9.13L2,9.74L7.45,14.47L5.82,21.5L12,17.77L18.18,21.5L16.54,14.47L22,9.74Z" />
```

Empty star:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M12,15.39L8.24,17.66L9.23,13.38L5.91,10.5L10.29,10.13L12,6.09L13.71,10.13L18.09,10.5L14.77,13.38L15.76,17.66M22,9.24L14.81,8.63L12,2L9.19,8.63L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24Z" />
```

To change their size, just update the attributes `height` and `width`.

To change their color, just update the attribute `fillColor` and set your yellow color.

Comment: SVG's doesn't work for the rating bar. Any idea why ?

Comment: Yeah, Vector XML does not work for ratingBar for some reason, it only shows one star stretched. If https://github.com/trello/victor is used to convert SVG's to PNG's on build-time, its possible to use SVG's.

Answer (score 4):

One Another way is create custom rating bar if you don't have any images follow below steps. This all file create in drawable folder.

**emptystar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#F1C332" android:pathData="M12,15.39L8.24,17.66L9.23,13.38L5.91,10.5L10.29,10.13L12,6.09L13.71,10.13L18.09,10.5L14.77,13.38L15.76,17.66M22,9.24L14.81,8.63L12,2L9.19,8.63L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24Z" />
</vector>
```

**full_star.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#F1C332" android:pathData="M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z" />
</vector>
```

**half_star.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="M12,15.89V6.59L13.71,10.63L18.09,11L14.77,13.88L15.76,18.16M22,9.74L14.81,9.13L12,2.5L9.19,9.13L2,9.74L7.45,14.47L5.82,21.5L12,17.77L18.18,21.5L16.54,14.47L22,9.74Z" >
</path>
</vector>
```

**food_ratingbar_full_empty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />
```

**food_ratingbar_full_filled.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/full_star" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/full_star" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/full_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/full_star" />
```

**food_rating_bar.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_empty" />

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/food_ratingbar_full_filled" />
```

**style.xml**

```
   <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/food_rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">23dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
   </style>
```

**In your layout**

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/ratingBarDish"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10"
style="@style/foodRatingBar"
android:isIndicator="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try to use this and use border image as a star https://github.com/ome450901/SimpleRatingBar as icon_starempty and icon_starfilled are your respective images

```
<com.willy.ratingbar.ScaleRatingBar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/deals_ratingbar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_newprice"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:outlineProvider="none"
                    app:srb_drawableEmpty="@drawable/icon_starempty"
                    app:srb_drawableFilled="@drawable/icon_starfilled"
                    app:srb_isIndicator="true"
                    app:srb_numStars="5"
                    app:srb_starHeight="@dimen/_10dp"
                    app:srb_starPadding="@dimen/_3dp"
                    app:srb_starWidth="@dimen/_10dp" />
```