# RatingBar without border

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I make `ratingBar` with a border like this: https://materialdoc.com/components/rating-bar/?

My `ratingBar` xml:

```
<RatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rating="2"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1" />
```

App styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This is what I get:
[image]

With color filters:

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** You can use custom drawable to rating bar.

Try this

**XML CODE**

```
 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/MyRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:stepSize="0.10"   <!-- Set Stepsize as per your need -->
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />
```

**THEME CODE**

```
  <style name="MyRatingBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
</style>
```

**custom_ratingbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ic_star_border_blue_24dp"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ic_star_border_blue_24dp"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ic_star_blue_24dp"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
</item>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATED**

Here is the source for the material icons https://material.io/icons/.

Use this source link to apply colour for your drawable [https://romannurik.github.io/](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit)

Hope it helps..!

Comment: `Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute`

Comment: I guess it doesn't support vector drawables

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

References :https://stackoverflow.com/a/37135661/8448886

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Border is default for android device,as you have to use Custom rating bar or any libraries.@Mike